# ModelState.isValid = false on production machine, true on development machine

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, modelstate, jquery-jtable

I'm using the jQuery jTable plugin for a CRUD table within my ASP.Net MVC 3 application. Running the code on my development machine works fine. However when I move the code to the production server, I cannot add new events/rows to jTable as I keep getting an error "Form is not valid!..." which is being triggered in the controller by `if(!ModelState.IsValid)`.

So next I grabbed the errors from the ModelState with `ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)` and put them into a JSON response, and this is why my ModelState is invalid: `"ErrorMessage=The value '15/08/2013 11:00:00' is not valid for Timestamp."`

So my question is, why is the that date-string okay for my development server but invalid for production?

Also, the model which is invalid was created by EF Database First, so I haven't set any DataAnnotations on my own. It seems that the default modelbinder doesn't work properly on my production system.

Could it possibly be due to the fact I'm using DD/MM/YY instead of MM/DD/YY? It's the Canadian way..

EDIT: Ah ha! It WAS because of the culture specific format, I first tried fixing it by switching the culture settings on the production environment from US to CA, but this still didn't fix it. So the next thing I did was added in a line into my `Web.config` within the `system.web` portion `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-CA" uiCulture="en-CA"/>` and now things are working smoothly. Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the edit, I found the cause of and solution to my problem. It was caused by an error being thrown by the automatic binding of parameters, and the reason it was having issues with dates on my production machine was due to the locale settings (dd/mm/yy vs mm/dd/yy) on that machine. To fix, I set the computers region settings (in the control panel), and also added a line into my Web.config.